# stoping jquery function when screen is smaller that 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my jQuery script. I am trying to make a responzive menu, with a submenu. The submenu is dropping down only when mouseenter its parent, but i need to stop this mouseenter function once i resize the screen (once it is smaller than 1000).

I even tried to add in the 'j' variable and made it a boleen. If the screen size is less than 1000, 'j' is set to 1.

```
var j = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if(j==0){
    console.log('enter function running');
    jQuery('ul[class^="nav-child"]').hide();
    jQuery('li[class^="item"]').one('mouseenter', function(){
      jQuery(this).find('ul').find('a').append('<br>');
      jQuery(this).find('ul').find('a').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    });
    if(j==0){
      jQuery('li[class^="item"]').mouseenter(function(){
        console.log('first mouse enter / j = ' +j);
        if(j==0){
          jQuery(this).find('ul').fadeIn(0);
        }
      });
      jQuery('li[class^="item"]').mouseleave(function(){
        console.log('first mouse leave');
        if(j==0){
          jQuery(this).find('ul').fadeOut(0);
        }
      });
    }
    jQuery('li[class$="urrent"]').find('a').css('color', 'grey');
  }

});
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
  var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
  console.log('j=1');
  j = 1;
  console.log(screenWidth);
  if(screenWidth<1000){
    console.log('if running');
    console.log('hidden');
    jQuery('.nav').find('li').css('float', 'none');
    jQuery('.row-grey').css('height', 'auto');
    jQuery('ul[class^="nav-child"]').show();
    //jQuery('.wrapper').replaceWith('.wrapper-collapsed');
  }else{
    j=0;
    console.log('else running');
    jQuery('div[class$="ow-grey"]').children().show();
    jQuery('.nav').find('li').css('float', 'left');
    jQuery('ul[class^="nav-child"]').hide();
    jQuery('li[class^="item"]').one('mouseenter', function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul').find('a').append(/*'<div class="stripe"></div>'*/'<br>');
    jQuery(this).find('ul').find('a').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    });
    if(j==0){
      jQuery('li[class^="item"]').mouseenter(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('ul').fadeIn(0);
        console.log('mouseenter running');
      });
      jQuery('li[class^="item"]').mouseleave(function(){
        console.log('mouseleave running');
        jQuery(this).find('ul').fadeOut(0);
      });
      jQuery('li[class$="urrent"]').find('a').css('color', 'grey');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the log:
[here is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGNyu.png)

I especialy dont understand how can there be j=1 in the log but the if is saying that it should run only if j==0

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe add a jsfiddle? Or add the HTML so I can rebuild it.

Comment: I'd reccomend reducing your code down to just the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why do you have a lot of `if(j==0){`? please rearrange your code, or better, create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) for this,

Comment: @evolutionxbox i did, but i dont know where inside this the probem is, otherwise the code is much longer

Comment: @Louskac - I'd recommend looking into [`MatchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). You can even add an event listener and run code when different sizes match.

Comment: @MoshFeu `if(j==0){ ... }` is there so many times, because i tried to point out the place where i think the problem is. I wanted to make sure the mouseenter function dosent get executed when screen is smaller than 1000 (thats when `j==0`).

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for the idea, but for some reason it still dosent work. Anyway i really like the idea :D i will defently make use of it